# Kubernetes cannot acess service

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

## **Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused**

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and now I wanted to keep on learning kubernetes. However currently I cannot acess my kubernetes deployment for some reason.

***`Deployment.yml`***

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment-c51e9e6b
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.7
          name: hello-kubernetes
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service-9878228b
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I'm pretty sure that this deployment has worked before so I assume that kubernetes has maybe not permissions to expose the port or something like that?

#### Additional information

- I'm running a minikube cluster.
- Output of kubectl get services: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evWbT.jpg

Comment: What is the output if you execute `kubectl get services`? In which way you access to the deployment? Is a minikube cluster?

Comment: You need to install or enable loadbalancer in your new environment. Your manifest file look correct

Comment: Yes, it's a minikube cluster I run it on my computer locally.
https://imgur.com/klgMiLY

Comment: Commands like `kubectl get services` should output text files, not PNG images.  If these details are important to your question, please include them directly in the question (not behind links) as text (not images).  It'd also help to know what URL exactly you're trying to access, from what context, and how you're getting that URL.

Answer (score 1):

why do you think you can access it via localhost directly?

If you need, please do the `port forward`, such as:

```
kubectl port-forward service/hello-service-9878228b 80:80
```

and you need keeping the console on.

then you should be fine to access it via http://localhost

Comment: `Unable to listen on port 80: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: bind: permission denied unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:80: bind: permission denied]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{80 8080}]`
If I forward the port to 8080 on my local machine it works fine. I just saw that all ports <1024 require special permissions. However if I change the port from `80` to `8080` I still do have to run the command but it should forward it automatically as far I know?

Comment: Have you tried granting the kubectl binary the capability to open ports using this command `sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/kubectl` ?

Comment: @Chrizz yes, you can adjust to any ports to local.

Answer (score 0):

To expose privileged ports (`< 1024`), you can give the container the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` - see [here](https://CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE).

See an example for setting `capabilities` under K8S Pod security context in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo-4
spec:
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-4
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["NET_ADMIN", "SYS_TIME"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using a service configuration that is align with a cloud configurations. If no external IPs are provided Kubernetes will try to provision an external TCP LoadBalancer which is available in Cloud Providers. For your configuration provide a external IP that you want to expose the service. This could be IP of a node in the cluster.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

```
type: LoadBalancer
externalIPs: 
- xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a ClusterIp service type rather than a loadbalancer type which will enable you to access it locally from your pc.